# Trabalhar com Windows Forms com designer no Linux?

Tags: c#, winforms, linux, mono, monodevelop

No Linux (Ubuntu) é possível criar aplicações com *Windows Forms* no `Mono` ou similar, usando um designer como o do *Visual Studio*?

Estou enfrentando problema, pois necessito desenvolver com o Windows Forms em um ambiente Linux com um designer parecido com o do Visual Studio.

Tentei usar o citado pelo [site do Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/archived/winforms_designer/), mas na hora de criar os eventos de clique, etc não é possível fazer tal ação.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Possível é, mas o [Windows Forms do Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/gui/winforms/) é bem problemático, de um modo geral as pessoas não usam. Alguns problemas podem ser vistos na [FAQ](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/faq/winforms/).

Em geral há preferência de uso do [GTK#](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/gui/gtksharp/). Anda tendo algumas outras opções, mas nada que pegou tração.

Note que a página do *designer* indica que ela está desatualizada. Ocorre até porque está essencialmente abandonado. Pode ser que seja um problema existente mesmo. Não espere muito suporte em algo que "ninguém" usa.

Uma alternativa é desenvolver no Visual Studio (sei que não pode, de acordo com outra pergunta, mas é uma opção) e depois usar no Mono. Não sei o quanto dará certo. Na teoria é para dar, mas na prática duvido que tudo funcione 100%.

De qualquer forma é possível programar sem o *designer*.

Considere usar o [MAUI](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-net-multi-platform-app-ui/?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Quando uso o GTK# é possível levar a solução para o Visual Studio? Porque o Windows Forms é principalmente para uso na sala de aula, pois pessoalmente o GTK# me auxilia bem.

Comment: Sim. Mas a experiência pode sofrer um pouco. Nem tudo no GTK funciona perfeitamente no Windows. Funciona, mas algumas coisas são diferentes e ficam esquisitas. Nada crítico, depende do gosto. Note que o GTK# também não tem recebido muita atenção, ele roda em cima de um GTK mais antigo, mas é a opção mais segura no Mono até o momento e até onde eu sei.